# tf.data.Dataset TypeError: If shallow structure is a sequence, input must also be a sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a Transformer model using English-French dataset.
I created the dataset using the preprocessing code below, which generates the dataset in the form of `((TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.int64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))`.

```py
  def encode(self, lang1, lang2):
    # Add <sos>, <eos> token
    lang1 = [self.tokenizer_src.vocab_size] + self.tokenizer_src.encode(
        lang1.numpy()) + [self.tokenizer_src.vocab_size + 1]
    
    lang2 = [self.tokenizer_trg.vocab_size] + self.tokenizer_trg.encode(
        lang2.numpy()) + [self.tokenizer_trg.vocab_size + 1]
    
    return lang1, lang2
  
  def tf_encode(self, src, trg):
    result_src, result_trg = tf.py_function(self.encode, [src, trg], [tf.int64, tf.int64])

    result_src.set_shape([None])
    result_trg.set_shape([None])

    return result_src, result_trg
  
  def make_batches(self, dataset, buffer_size, batch_size):
    dataset = (
        dataset
        .cache()
        .shuffle(buffer_size)
        .map(self.tf_encode, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
        .padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes=([self.maxlen], [self.maxlen])))
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: ((x, y), y),
                          num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE) 
    return dataset
  
  def tokenization(self, buffer_size, batch_size):

    # Tokenize datasets & Make batches
    train_dataset = self.make_batches(self.train_dataset, buffer_size, batch_size)
    val_dataset = self.make_batches(self.val_dataset, buffer_size, batch_size)
    test_dataset = self.make_batches(self.test_dataset, buffer_size, batch_size)

    return train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset
```

The reason that I created the dataset in the form of ((x, y), y) is that when I pass the dataset as `inputs` to the `call()` below, `inputs` get only the first element of the tuple.

Then, I created an input_signature to pass the train_dataset as inputs to the model, as follows:

```py
    @tf.function(input_signature=[
        ((tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, MAXLEN), dtype=tf.int64),
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, MAXLEN), dtype=tf.int64)),
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, MAXLEN), dtype=tf.int64)), 
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.bool)
         ])
    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        inp, tar = inputs

        enc_padding_mask, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask = self.create_masks(inp, tar)

        enc_output = self.encoder(inp, training, enc_padding_mask)  # (batch_size, inp_seq_len, d_model)

        dec_output, attention_weights = self.decoder(
            tar, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask)
        # |dec_output| = (batch_size, tar_seq_len, d_model)

        final_output = self.final_layer(dec_output)  # (batch_size, tar_seq_len, target_vocab_size)

        return final_output, attention_weights
```

But I keep getting the following TypeError:

```py
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'transformer' (type Transformer).
    
    If shallow structure is a sequence, input must also be a sequence. Input has type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>.
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'transformer' (type Transformer):
      • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 100), dtype=int64)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 100), dtype=int64)')
      • training=True
```

I have tried various methods to match the element_spec of my train_dataset and input_signature, and to split the train_dataset passed in as `inputs` into `inp` and `tar`, like in the `call()`, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are some typos, which can raise the error.

See this lines:

```
    @tf.function(input_signature=[
    ((tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, MAXLEN), dtype=tf.int64),
     tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, MAXLEN), dtype=tf.int64)),
     tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, MAXLEN), dtype=tf.int64)), 
     tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.bool)
     ])
```

The number of parentheses `(())` is not compatible in this line.

Comment: Thanks for comment!



I changed input_signature like this:



`
 @tf.function(input_signature=[
        (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, MAXLEN), dtype=tf.int64),
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, MAXLEN), dtype=tf.int64)),
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.bool)
         ])
`

and it solved that TypeError!